# Load Store Queue - estimate time of calculations

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm taking a course in computer architecture and came across this problem in one of his "past exam questions" in studying for my current exam. The question goes like this:

"The table below lists a sequence of loads and stores in the LSQ, when their one/two input operands are made available, and their computed effective addresses. **Estimate when the address calculation happened for each ld/st** *and* **when each ld/st accesses the data memory.** (Add two more columns, in the table below, corresponding to each of the underlined items to answer this question.) Assume that the processor does no memory dependence prediction to speculatively issue loads.  "

[image]

Now I've searched through his lecture slides as well as the book for LOAD STORE QUEUES and have found nothing that helps me answer this question. I tried looking on youtube to see if there were any videos, and while there's plenty on LSQ, OOOLSQ, IOLSQ etc, none of them cover estimating when the address calc happened or when they access the data memory.

Is there anyone that's familiar with this type of problem that would be willing to help me out?

I'm assuming that time of calculation starts at 0 and only takes 1 unit of time for the LD, and also that it accesses memory immediately after (so time to calc + 1 time unit). I see no dependencies in the load, so I would think the same for them, but I know for a fact it's not just "1,2 - 3,4 - 5,6 etc...

Comment: Rephrase the question to 'How expensive are each address calculation for the inputs and how expensive time wise is each data access for the inputs?'

Comment: Why is that @L0uis?

Comment: All i did was quote the exact question from the provided example.

Comment: There's an order to loading and calculating the address for the load. Its not straight down the line. I beleive you are being asked to determine this: In general, memory dependence prediction predicts whether two memory operations are dependent, that is, if they interact by accessing the same memory location. Besides using store to load (RAW or true) memory dependence prediction for the out-of-order scheduling of loads and stores, other applications of memory dependence prediction have been proposed.

Comment: The table shows you when one or both operands are available and it shows the dependencies between loads and previous stores. I don't know how much time it takes to calculate the address. But any access has to way until the operands are ready. Looks similar to [this](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cs6810/hw/hw15-5.html) question.

Comment: It's identical pretty much! If only there were an answer sheet attached or explanation :P